# trigger a clickevent in a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML Code

```
<ul id="linkjess">
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('medewerkers', '1000');">medewerkers 1000</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('medewerkers', '1001');">medewerkers 1001</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('medewerkers', '2001');">medewerkers 2001</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('kantoren', '101');">Kantoor 101</a></li>
</ul>
```

Script :

```
<script>
  function setfolder(type, id)
  { 
          $(".folder-box").each(function(index, element) {
            if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == type)
                {
                  $(element).find("img").trigger("click")
                }
          })
  }
</script>
```

if i click on anchor tag having text medewerker 1000 it goes to the folder medewerker 
how can i make sure it must go to medewerker > 1000 ?

EDIT:

i have 3 folders named (example) a b and medewerkers

medewerkers has 3 folders in it (subfolders) 1000 1001 1002

if i click on the link(medewerker 1000) it goes to inside map medewerkers 
what i want is it must go to medewerkers and in the folder 1000.

EDIT:

```
  { 
          $(".folder-box").each(function(index, element) {
            if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == type)
                {
                  $(element).find("img").trigger("click")
                }
                  if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == id)
                  {
                     $(element).find("img").trigger("click")
                  }
          })
  }
```

if i use this i must click twice on the same link to do what i want.

my question is how can i make it not 2 x click but once

Comment: Can't you just check if (id > 1000)?

Comment: Where is your `items` as your using `.item-title` ?

Comment: Please add the html for you .folder-box elements to see how they are structured.

Comment: http://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript the structure is here

Comment: You could use an id for each subfolder or something that could help you identify the _index_ you are looking for.  Posting your html structure for this would help in giving you a much clearer answer.

Comment: http://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript  the html structure is here (there is a lot of code  to post it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your subfolders are named just with the id (1000, 1001, 101) you could try something like this:

```
<script>
  function setfolder(type, id)
  { 
          $(".folder-box").each(function(index, element) {
            if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == type)
            {
                $(element).find("img").trigger("click");
                var subFolder = $(element).find(".item-title");

                if ($(subFolder).find(".item-title").html() == id)
                  $(subFolder).find("img").trigger("click");
                }
            }
          })
  }
</script>
```

UPDATE:
You function could look like this:

```
function setfolder(type, id) {

  $(".folder-box").find(".item-title:contains(" + type + ")").find(".item-title:contains(" +  id + ")").find("img").trigger("click");
}
```

I have created a html structure based on your link. If your output is different you need to adjust the script to your needs.

**CSS**

```
<style>
.folder-box {
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 0;
    border:solid 1px #edeae9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 9px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 9px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 7px 9px 5px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-radius:5px;
}


.item-title img{
    max-width:15%;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: thin solid green;
}

.item-title {
    padding:5px 0px 0px 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width:150px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:11px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="linkjess">
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('Medewerkers', '1000');">medewerkers 1000</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('Medewerkers', '1001');">medewerkers 1001</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('Medewerkers', '1002');">medewerkers 1002</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:setfolder('Kantoor', '101');">Kantoor 101</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="folder-box">
  <div class="item-title"><img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/education-folder-icon-15.jpg" alt="folder" />Medewerkers
    <div class="item-title">
      <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/education-folder-icon-15.jpg" alt="folder" />1000</div> 
    <div class="item-title">
      <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/education-folder-icon-15.jpg" alt="folder" />1001</div>
    <div class="item-title">
       <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/education-folder-icon-15.jpg" alt="folder" />1002</div>
  </div>

 <div class="item-title"><img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/education-folder-icon-15.jpg" alt="folder" />Kantoor
    <div class="item-title">
      <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/education-folder-icon-15.jpg" alt="folder" />101</div> 
 </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
function setfolder(type, id) {

  $(".folder-box").find(".item-title:contains(" + type + ")").find(".item-title:contains(" +  id + ")").find("img").trigger("click");
}

$("img").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css('border','thin solid red');
});
</script>
```

Here is the working [sample](http://codepen.io/monica_eds/pen/PGaavE).

Comment: The first click to expand the parent folder might be needed, and then select the subfolder. Ddoes solve your problem? I have updated my answer.

Comment: it must click the subfolder 1000 aswel

Comment: is it possible to open th efolder 1000  after the link is clicked?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by opening the folder? put you required action in the _onclick_ event.

Comment: the problem is that if i click on the link it opens the first folder than it loads everything when it's loading everything ur code doesnt work i need it to open the subfolder 1000 in this case

Comment: Nvm i found a different way of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
 <script>
      function setfolder(type, id)
      { 
          if(id > 1000)
           {
              $(".folder-box").each(function(index, element) {
                if ($(element).find(".item-title").html() == type)
                    {
                      $(element).find("img").trigger("click")
                    }
              })

           }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: the 1000 is just the "name" of the folder it could be 1 or 1000000 or even abs